# Manage Multiple Threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, operating-system

Function gen() generates a string, which is a command to be passed into os.system().

I need to start 20 threads at the same time, call gen() for each thread, and run the command gen() gives me in each thread. (parallel)

Once a command finishes executing in a thread, I want to call gen() again to generate another command, and run that command in the same thread.

I want to to keep doing this until 10 minutes have passed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/), hope this helps.

Its actually not that hard

but keep in mind when working with threads which use the same variable to use [locks](http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm#locks)!

Comment: This actually helped, Thanks.

Comment: If there is no better answer, I'll accept this tomorrow. Thanks again.